# Just echo env variables but not bash funcs

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

Is there a way to echo bash variables but not bash funcs?

I can do this

```
env | grep -v 'BASH_FUNC'
```

but they are usually multiline, so other lines from the functions get echoed.

Comment: Does `export` do what you want?

Comment: maybe it does, I just tried it, looks ok? can you show how to strip the "declare -x" part?

Comment: `export | cut -d" " -f3-`

Answer (score 1):

To list all environment variables, but not exported functions:

```bsh
for n in `compgen -e`; do echo "$n=${!n}"; done
```

Here `compgen -e` lists the names of the variables; the `echo` outputs the names with their values.
Maybe you want to use `${!n@Q}` instead of `${!n}` to have the values quoted, so the output can be read back from a file, or used with `eval`.

(Edit:)
NOTE: this does not work too well when arrays are involved; unlike `env`, which ignores arrays, this prints the value with index `0` for arrays.
(For associative arrays, if no index `0` is present, `name=` is printed.)
For clues on how to handle this, see the answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525296/bash-check-if-variable-is-array).

Answer (score 0):

So I did it like so using a subshell, and unsetting all the bash funcs:

```
   (
       # in subshell

       for line in `declare -F | awk '{print $3}'`; do
          unset -f "$line"  # unset all bash funcs
       done

        env
    )
```

but I bet there is a better way